# ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library on Flask

Tags: python, zbar

Im trying to use pyzbar 0.1.4 on a Flask Server in Docker

The image was created by us, based in python 2.7 taken from alpine.

Install ZBar by

```
apk update
apk add zbar
```

Im getting the following error when running dockerfile

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyzbar/pyzbar.py", line 8, in <module>
   from .wrapper import (
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py", line 166, in <module>
   c_uint_p,    # minor
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py", line 159, in zbar_function
   return prototype((fname, load_libzbar()))
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py", line 135, in load_libzbar
   raise ImportError('Unable to find zbar shared library')
ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library
```

Im trying to decode a QR image using that library

Dockerfile

```
FROM buffetcontainerimages.azurecr.io/base/buffetcloud-python:0.1
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
COPY wheeldir /opt/app/wheeldir
COPY *requirements.txt /opt/app/src/
RUN pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=/opt/app/wheeldir \
-r /opt/app/src/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=/opt/app/wheeldir \
-r /opt/app/src/test-requirements.txt
COPY . /opt/app/src/
WORKDIR /opt/app/src
RUN python setup.py install
EXPOSE 5000
CMD dronedemo
```

And requirements.txt

```
requests>=2.18.4
flask>=0.12.2
mechanize>=0.3.6
regex>=2.4.136
PyPDF2>=1.26.0
bs4>=4.5.3
pyzbar>=0.1.4
openpyxl>=2.5.0
selenium>=3.9.0
matplotlib>=2.1.2
```

When pip install zbar

```
pip install zbar
Collecting zbar
Downloading zbar-0.10.tar.bz2
...
zbarmodule.h:26:18: fatal error: zbar.h: No such file or directory
#include <zbar.h>
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile and stuff?

Comment: This looks strange. dll usually means windows. then youre showing a stack trace with '/usr/lib/python2.7/...' which tells me youre on a *nix system.. can you please post your dockerfile (a must) and python req file just in case.

Comment: @Ivonet Added dockerfile and requirements

Comment: Where is this image coming from? What is it based of? `scratch`? `debian`? how is the package installed?

Comment: On another note: pyzbar looks like its a wrapper FOR windows, https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/ so this is not what you want to use.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi The image was created by us, based in python 2.7 taken from alpine.

The package is installed by 
apk update
apk add zbar

Comment: At any rate, i _think_ `pyzbar` (they have a wheel for "any" environment -- but something tells me they didnt test it) is completely out of the question since it wants to be installed on windows, try just pip installing `zbar`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple test, looks good.

```
FROM python:2.7
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential libzbar-dev && \
    pip install zbar
```

i tried alpine.. but the `zbar` lib is only available in the edge branch -- trying to get it to work was more trouble than it was worth.

<s>PS. beware of images that are not in the docker repo.</s> -- didnt know it was your image

---

Working example:

```
$ docker build -t yourimagenamehere .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM python:2.7
 ---> 9e92c8430ba0
... trunc...
Successfully built d951cd32ea74
Successfully tagged yourimagenamehere:latest
$ docker run -it --rm yourimagenamehere 
Python 2.7.14 (default, Dec 12 2017, 16:55:09) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import zbar
>>>
```

Comment: Where you get the image Python:2.7 ? Alpine

Comment: @NicolasFuchs from the official docker repo (https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) if you run this, it will automagically download it for you and built the image for you -- you dont need to have it, docker is smart enough to go and fetch it.   Pay attention to the *Working example* and look for the `$` and you can do this yourself

Comment: This one seems to be bigger in size than `zbar-tools`.

Answer (score 18):

In Ubuntu install zbar-tools

```
sudo apt-get install zbar-tools
```

Comment: This one seems to be smaller in size than `libzbar-dev`.

Answer (score 2):

In **Ubuntu** terminal simply run this command and this will install zbar in your global package

```
sudo apt-get install zbar-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue (happy to have found this thread). Not sure if this has already been solved but this might help you or future devs.

As usual, it worked on my machine locally but couldn't get it to work in a container

What I tried initially:

- Building an image based on a Python3 image

What solved the issue:

- Build with FROM ubuntu:18.04
- Within Ubuntu I was able to install the zbar shared library. According to https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/ we need `sudo apt-get install libzbar0`
- Set `LC_ALL` & `LANG` ENV variables (not sure why, it was provided in an additional error)
- Within requirements.txt downgrade `Pillow==8.4.0` to `Pillow==6.2.2`

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update -y
# Get's shared library for zbar
RUN apt-get install -y libzbar0
# Installs Python
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev build-essential

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Initially encountered an issue that indicated I had to set these ENVs
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]
```

And requirements.txt

```
fastapi==0.67.0
Pillow==6.2.2
pyzbar==0.1.8
urllib3==1.26.7
uvicorn==0.12.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I grea with the second commend on your post, but you might want to try to install the pyzbar dependency through pip.

```
FROM buffetcontainerimages.azurecr.io/base/buffetcloud-python:0.1
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel pyzbar
COPY wheeldir /opt/app/wheeldir
COPY *requirements.txt /opt/app/src/
RUN pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=/opt/app/wheeldir \
-r /opt/app/src/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=/opt/app/wheeldir \
-r /opt/app/src/test-requirements.txt
RUN pip install -y pyzbar
COPY . /opt/app/src/
WORKDIR /opt/app/src
RUN python setup.py install
EXPOSE 5000
CMD dronedemo
```