# Heroku ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py, importerror, zbar

I am trying to make a system that can generate and read qr codes via my discord bot. My code functions properly in my editor however, it returns `ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library` once pushed to heroku. I've tried looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48792965/importerror-unable-to-find-zbar-shared-library-on-flask) as well as on the [pyzbar library](https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/) to no avail. I'm on Windows running Python 3.9.4 64-bit, any help is appreciated greatly.

Below is the full relevant code:

```
import discord
import pyqrcode
import re
import os
import shutil
import requests
import uuid
from discord.ext import commands
from PIL import Image
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="p.")

class Bot(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(help="p.qr {link} or {QR code image}")
    async def qr(self, ctx, *, link=None):
        if link == None:
            try:
                url = ctx.message.attachments[0].url
            except IndexError:
                await ctx.reply("Invalid response. Please provide a `link` or a `QR code image`.", mention_author=False)
            else:
                if (url[0:26] == "https://cdn.discordapp.com"):
                    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
                    imageName = (str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".jpg")
                    with open(imageName, "wb") as out_file:
                        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, out_file)
            decoded_image = str(decode(Image.open(imageName)))
            os.remove(imageName)
            filter = re.findall("'([^']*)'", (decoded_image))
            try:
                await ctx.reply(filter[0], mention_author=False)
            except IndexError:
                await ctx.reply("Invalid response. Please provide a `link` or a `QR code image`.", mention_author=False)
        else:
            open("QR.png", "x")
            qr = pyqrcode.create(link)
            qr.png("QR.png", scale=6)
            with open("QR.png", "rb") as file:
                await ctx.reply(file=discord.File(file, "QR.png"), mention_author=False)
            os.remove("QR.png")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Bot(client))
```

And the error message from Heroku:

```
2021-07-15T21:44:32.535519+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-07-15T21:44:32.535687+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 606, in _load_from_module_spec
2021-07-15T21:44:32.536282+00:00 app[worker.1]:     spec.loader.exec_module(lib)
2021-07-15T21:44:32.536294+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
2021-07-15T21:44:32.536564+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-07-15T21:44:32.536781+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/cogs/bot.py", line 18, in <module>
2021-07-15T21:44:32.537046+00:00 app[worker.1]:     from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
2021-07-15T21:44:32.537084+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyzbar/pyzbar.py", line 7, in <module>
2021-07-15T21:44:32.537332+00:00 app[worker.1]:     from .wrapper import (
2021-07-15T21:44:32.537342+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py", line 139, in <module>
2021-07-15T21:44:32.537563+00:00 app[worker.1]:     zbar_version = zbar_function(
2021-07-15T21:44:32.537566+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py", line 136, in zbar_function
2021-07-15T21:44:32.537871+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return prototype((fname, load_libzbar()))
2021-07-15T21:44:32.537872+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py", line 115, in load_libzbar
2021-07-15T21:44:32.538066+00:00 app[worker.1]:     libzbar, dependencies = zbar_library.load()
2021-07-15T21:44:32.538070+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyzbar/zbar_library.py", line 65, in load
2021-07-15T21:44:32.538461+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise ImportError('Unable to find zbar shared library')
2021-07-15T21:44:32.538704+00:00 app[worker.1]: ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library
```

Comment: Did you add the [heroku buildpack for Zbar](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/generalui/heroku-buildpack-zbar)?

Comment: Yep, doesn't seem to have made any difference and the error message is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

@ethanpartyof1, this may be late, but I have found a solution to make this work.

## 1. Add the APT buildpack to heroku

Run `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt` in the app directory.

## 2. Make a file named `Aptfile` and add this to it:

```
libzbar0
libzbar-dev
```

After completing these 2 steps, commit and push. It should work without any hassles.