# How can I use the ZBar libraries in a python Azure function?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am attempting to write a simple Azure Function app in Python.

My function app work fine in the local simulator but when I attempt to publish it to Azure, it fails with this error:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.ProcessPDF Result: Failure
Exception: ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module.
```

My understanding is that the ZBar libraries cannot be found by the runtime environment (Lunix x64 for Azure Functions).

My "requirements.txt" file does not contain `zbar` but it does contain `pyzbar` which is the wrapper I am using.

My question is: how can I deploy the necessary libraries in the host in Azure functions?

Comment: Try adding zbar=0.10 in your requirements.txt and redeploy your function app? Also, Validate if zbar library is present in venv in your local function folder?

Comment: Attemting to add zbar to the requirements.txt file causes the deployment to fail. I'm not sure what you mean by your second suggestion: the zbar library is not deployed with my function. It's part of the Python deployment in windows but should be installed using apt-get on Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried adding pyzbar[zbar]  in the requirements.txt of my Azure Function and deployed the function app in Azure Portal successfully like below:-***

**My requirements.txt**

[image]

I used the below commands to deploy my function app to azure from local env:-

```bash
func azure functionapp publish <function-app-name>
```

```bash
func azure functionapp publish <app_name> --build remote
```

**The remote build will include pyzbar package in the deployment**

**Output:-**

[image]

***pyzbar got installed successfully like below:-***

[image]

Function got deployed in Azure Portal, Refer below:-

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]

**Function:-**

[image]

***As Zbar library cannot be installed with pip cause it has a dependency on the Zbar package that needs to be installed from here- https://zbar.sourceforge.net/download.html, You can create a custom function docker image and install your Zbar library like below*** :-

**Custom docker image :-**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0

# Install zbar libraries
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libzbar0
```

**Build your docker image:-**

```
docker build -t <your_image_name> .
```

**Update your function app to use the docker image by referencing it in Host.json like below:-**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "name": "MyFunction",
      "docker": {
        "image": "<your_image_name>"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

> **References:-**
>
> Refer the post's below for more insights:-
>
> [python - ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library on Flask -
> Stack
> Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48792965/importerror-unable-to-find-zbar-shared-library-on-flask)
> By Mise Javier Buzzi stefan Kautuk Dwivedi
>
> [Add support to load library externally · Issue #40 ·
> NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar ·
> GitHub](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/issues/40) By
> nickovs

Comment: Thank yo for the detailed answer. Unfortunately, using a custom dcker image for azure function requires a "premium" service level which is actually more expensive (and quite a lot too) thank running a full app service. I now realize I should have added that to my initial question.
I will still accept your answer, though, since it seems it is the only one at this time.